# How to query a table for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Suppose I have a table for a set of Roles containing data like Business Analyst, Quality Assurance analyst etc. All are indexed by a unique Id.
I have another table for People again indexed by a unique Id.

I created a third table for people who have multiple roles called "`PersonRole`". If I want to query PersonRole for someone with a Business Analyst and Developer Role (assuming an Id of 2 and 3), what type of query do I need? Should I be building it with sub queries or unions?

I have tried this but it returns nothing.

```
select * from PersonRole 
inner join Person on Person.Id = PersonRole.PersonId
where Person.Id = 3
and PersonRole.RoleId = 2
and PersonRole.RoleId = 3
```

Comment: Change your AND to an OR. A single row can't have multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Use EXISTS subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query for someone who has both roles, I would suggest an aggregation query with a `having` clause.  Here is one way to write this:

```
select pr.PersonId
from PersonRole pr
group by pr.PersonId
having sum(case when pr.RoleId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when pr.RoleId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you want more details from the `Person` table, you can join that back in.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you! although I am a little confused by the syntax in the having clause. Is there somewhere I could read about it?

Comment: @Michael . . . It is counting the number of rows that match each of the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx)

```
select * from PersonRole 
inner join Person on Person.Id = PersonRole.PersonId
where Person.Id = 3
and (PersonRole.RoleId = 2 OR PersonRole.RoleId = 3)
```

Alternatively [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177682.aspx)

```
select * from PersonRole 
inner join Person on Person.Id = PersonRole.PersonId
where Person.Id = 3
and PersonRole.RoleId IN (2,3)
```

Comment: This gets me closer, but I still want only people who are an Analyst AND a Developer rather than an Analyst or a Developer. Is there a way to refine the query or maybe its in the table structure itself that needs to be changed to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from PersonRole 
inner join Person on Person.Id = PersonRole.PersonId
where Person.Id = 3
OR PersonRole.RoleId = 2 OR
PersonRole.RoleId = 3
```

OR

```
select * from PersonRole 
inner join Person on Person.Id = PersonRole.PersonId
where Person.Id = 3
OR PersonRole.RoleId IN (2 ,3)
```

Comment: ok, but so how do I retrieve a person who is a Business analyst AND a Developer rather than a person who is one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

or join on `personRole` twice, once for each condition you want:

```
select p.* from 
Person p inner join
PersonRole r2 on 
p.Id = r2.PersonId and
r2.RoleId = 2 inner join
PersonRole r3 on 
p.Id = r3.PersonId and
r3.RoleId = 3
where 
p.Id = 3
```